# How to search for numbers with MATCH() AGAINST()

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named: `name` , type: `text`, `FULLTEXT` index

and I try to find an IP address in the column `name` with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE  MATCH(ip) AGAINST ('127.0.0.1')
```

but I got 0 as a result , it worked only with letter, with number it does not. How to fix it?

Comment: Is there a column called `ip` or are you looking for that in `name`?  Can you maybe show the raw data a little more clearly?

Comment: Could it be that most rows contain the `127.0.0.1` in them? The [built in mysql fulltext engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) won't return anything if the result set is more than the half of the table you are searching in. Try searching with [boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: This isn't how you use full text.

Comment: Do it in PHP.  faster.  easier than trying to make sql do...anything

Answer (score 0):

try 
`SELECT * FROM data WHERE  ip LIKE '%127.0.0.1%'`

or if ip address is in name column, than
`SELECT * FROM data WHERE  name LIKE '%127.0.0.1%'`

Comment: While it would certainly work, i'm affraid it could be terribly slow, compared to a working fulltext index supported query.

Comment: a `LIKE` query that uses `%` at the start of the search string will have to search the entire database to find all matching records. This is why they are slow. You can get away with it on a small table, but as the amount of data grows, the query will get slower and slower and slower.

Answer (score 0):

What does the `ip` field contain? Is it a single IP address or a load of them?

If it's just a single address, you don't need to use `MATCH` or `LIKE` or any other specialist query; just use `=`.  ie:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ip = '127.0.0.1'
```

If it's more than one IP address in there per record, I suggest you consider splitting it out into a separate cross-reference table, as it will make things a lot easier to manage when you need to do search queries like this. Then the answer again reverts to just use `=`, with a join on the IP table.

```
SELECT * FROM data d
INNER JOIN ipAddresses i on i.dataID=d.id
WHERE i.ip = '127.0.0.1'
```